# Wordpress won't allow me to download updates, plugins or themes

Tags: wordpress, apache, php-7.2

Two days ago we've received a project to realize for my school. We have to build a website using Wordpress.
As told in the title, I can not manage to install plugins, themes, updates and probably some things more from the admin panel.

When I try to download a theme, for example, I get the following message: "Can not locate themes directory".

However, I've been able to install two themes (actually one theme and its parent one, dont know if it matters) by downloading them as zip, and unzip in the wp-content/themes folder.

I've also added some lines to my wp-config.php file:

```
define('FTP_BASE', '/wordpress');
define('FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/wordpress/content');
define('FTP_PLUGIN_DIR', '/wordpress/wp-content/plugins');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__).'/wordpress/wp-content');
define('WP_PLUGIN_DIR', dirname(__FILE__). '/wordpress/wp-content/plugins');

define('WP_CONTENT_URL', '127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content');
define('WP_PLUGIN_URL', '127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/plugins');
```

I am using Ubuntu with apache2, mysql and PHP7.2

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Check your permissions on the target folder, particular if you could unzip it there from the command line (or whatever you used) and WP can't.

Comment: Permissions look fine to me, writable and readable for "others" group

Comment: This maybe a user ownership problem, do you get an error when attempting to add to media folder does it ask for ftp credentials? if so even though the folder permissions are correct its the owner of the folder you have an issue with

Answer (score 0):

check your site origin at file manager and left click to make sure that your site has permission to create/upload/etc activities

Comment: I already tried changing the permissions but still it does not change anything.
For the site location, it seems good to me (/var/www/html/wordpress for the server, localhost/wordpress in the settings)